# How to access data passed into Flask with an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I am working on a project that displays hotel and airbnb data using flask and a sql database.  We are trying to create a "favorite button" so the user can favorite/unfavorite listings.  I've got an AJAX call to a Flask endpoint that will the make corresponding SQL queries to the "favorites" table.  My problem is, I can't seem to access the data I'm passing into Flask.

Here is my AJAX call on the client-side:

```
function unfavoriteClicked(uid, itemid, type){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/unfavorite",
        data:{uid:uid, itemid:itemid, type:type},
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        success: function(data) {    
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR) {
            alert("error: " + jqXHR.status);
        }
    });
}
```

And here is my Flask code:

```
@app.route('/unfavorite', methods=["GET","POST"])
def unfavorite():
    if request.method == "POST":
      return request.form
return "this shouldn't happen"
```

Note that I've taken the SQL logic and other things out since I've figured out that I am not accessing the data correctly in Flask.

I am sure that the AJAX request goes through, because when I return something like "hello", it shows up in the console log.  However, when I try to access the data dictionary I'm passing in, it returns a "500 internal server error" or some other kind of error depending on what I'm trying to access.  I've tried to access a bunch of different things from looking at other stackoverflow posts (like request.form['data'], request.data, request.args, etc) but nothing seems to allow me to access the data.  However, it does seem to allow me to access "request.method".

I was wondering if there is something fundamental that I am missing here that would be a reason why I cannot pass in data to Flask?  Or any other suggestions for doing this "favorite" button are appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So considering the main issue that you want to tackle is accessing the data that is been passed by your web page using Ajax. I have a solution which might work in your case.

So there are two parts in which i will explain how you can solve this problem.

1) Passing the data to your python controller/function to further process the data.

```
   $.post("url_to_which_you_want_to_pass_data", {variable_name_to_access_in_python:any_value/variable_from_front_end},
         function(response, status){
                       call_back_function_code  
         });
```

2) Accessing the data that has been passed from the webpage in python flask

```
   @app.route('/unfavorite', methods=["GET","POST"])
   def unfavourite:
      if request.method == "POST":
         any_variable_name = request.form.get("variable_name_to_access_in_python","")
         print(any_variable_name) #If you want to print
         return any_variable_name #If you want to see any_variable_name on web
      return None
```

Hope it Helps! Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best option, but its worked for me.

JavaScript:

```
    var data = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    var frontend_data = {'list':data}

    $.ajax({
        url: "/unfavorite",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(frontend_data),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
          console.log("Result:");
          console.log(result);
        }
    });
```

Flask:

```
    @app.post('/unfavorite')
    def unfavorite():
        data = request.get_json()
        print(data['data'])  #[1, 2, 3, 4]
        return jsonify(data)
```